# Is it true that for any natural number n, that nth order Taylor polynomial of any polynomial at $\vec0$ is just the polynomial itself?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, polynomials, reference-request, taylor-expansion

Is it true that for any natural number $n$, that $n$-th order Taylor polynomial of any polynomial at $\vec0$ is just itself ? (If $n\ge$degree of the polynomial)

For example if $f(x_1,\dots,x_m)$ is a polynomial, then $n$-th order Taylor polynomial of $f$ at $\vec 0$ is just $f$ itself ? i.e. $f(x_1,\dots,x_m)=4x_1^2x_2+5x_3^3x_5+7x_1^3+2x_4,n\ge4$ etc.

Comment: yes, it's true, but as I recall, the proof is pretty tedious. In the one-dimensional case, I know that Spivak's Calculus has a proof (somewhere in Chapter 20, on Taylor polynomials). In the multivariable case, I know that Henri Cartan's Differential Calculus text (Chapter 7) contains a proof. Anyway, just try it out in the 2-variable case by writing out the taylor polynomial for small $n$. You should see how to generalize.

Comment: Thanks @peek-a-boo, that helps me a lot, I can accept this as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JUst repeating the comments: Yes, it's true, but as I recall, the proof is pretty tedious. In the one-dimensional case, I know that Spivak's Calculus has a proof (somewhere in Chapter 20, on Taylor polynomials). In the multivariable case, I know that Henri Cartan's Differential Calculus text (Chapter 7) contains a proof. Anyway, just try it out in the 2-variable case by writing out the taylor polynomial for small n. You should see how to generalize.